# Get PayPal transaction details by Payer ID. PayPal return only the Payer ID

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

PayPal returning a PayerID on every transaction. I need to get the Email Address of the Client and other transaction details.

Return URL like this, attaching PayerID in it. Here is the example: https://myreturnurl?PayerID=WA7G59W5XVSY

Do the PayPal have any API to fetch transaction data by PayerID.

Or if you have any suggestion related to this query.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: The person who gave negative vote, please pass the comment. What's the reason?

Comment: looking for same response, could not find the solution yet.